# What would you do in Knn specific case

Tags: data-mining

I'd like to know what would you do in this specific and unrealistic case appliying Knn when k = 1, k = 2 and k = 3.

- Class 1 individuals: **[1,1] [2,2] [2,4] [2,5]**
- Class 2 individuals: **[3,1] [4,1] [4,2]**
- individual to classify: **[2,1]**

Plot:

[image: Knn test plot]

I don't know if there would be any criteria rather than the generation order to choose the class it belongs.

Comment: k=3 seems reasonable (or 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When k=3** it is a simple case, the 3 nearest examples share the same distance to the new sample. Two of them are from class 1 and a single example is from class 2, so the new sample will be classified as class 1.

**When k=2** it is more tricky. Assuming that the 2 features (x,y) share similar importance to the classification (otherwise distances should be calculated with some predetermined weights), you can:

1. Choose randomly 2 out of the 3 candidates (you are basically acknowledging that for this case, your model doesn't have enough information for classification based on 2-NN).
2. take all candidates into account (i.e. for cases like this you go to 3-NN).

**When k=1**, same options as with the k=2 case (you will still need to go up to 3-NN).

In this specific case, because your 3 nearest neighbors are all of the same distance, I would choose to use K-NN. However for a similar case with 4 samples at the same distance, 2 of each class, I would choose randomly (not going to 5-NN).